# How do you use 'reclass' in GRASS?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, sextante-qgis-plugin, reclassify

It could be user error, but for some reason, the reclass tool is just hanging and hanging...

QGIS 1.8
Compiled against GDAL/OGR 1.9.2
Ubuntu 12.04.1

- Running the tool from the Sextante toolbox
- Input is a 10' cellsize raster ~10mi x 10mi in area
- grass region cellsize = 10
- Reclass file is in order from what I can gather from the help

When run: 
- There is no process operating in the system monitor
- Dialogue hangs and cursor shows progress spinny thing...

Not sure what else to say?

Does the GRASS tool run from this dialogue on a .tif? Or does it have to be run from the GRASS tools specifically?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to run the reclass in GRASS directly, and report back? You will have to **import the raster into GRASS**. GRASS modules do not work on external formats.

Comment: Ok I got the reclass tool to work in GRASS directly - and it works really well, actually (love that I can have the reclass text file open while I have the tool open too - just so I can 'tweak' the reclass, then run the tool to see the update!)

I'm going to try to run the tool again now that I have a GRASS dataset put together...

Comment: **r.reclass only takes as input integer values** (there's a reason for it),and to do it cast the value to int type. if you want to reclassify (values from x to y should be z) use r.recode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running reclass in GRASS directly solved the problem thanks to @Micha for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Sextante is still in active development and most likely there are a lot of bugs that occur in certain situations and on different systems.

In the meantime try to use the SAGA sextante toolset. It also has a reclass tool called "Reclassify Grid Values" in the "Grid - Tools" toolbox.

And don't forget to submit a bug to the qgis development team.

Comment: You can report it here: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/sextante/issues (r.reclass takes just nanoseconds since it internally only generates a lookup table!).